# Application crash when back is pressed in camera activity

Tags: android, android-studio

here is my code

```
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCodeC, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if this is the result of our camera image request
  

    if (requestCodeC == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // getting bitmap of the image
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) Objects.requireNonNull( Objects.requireNonNull( data ).getExtras() ).get( "data" );
        // displaying this bitmap in imageview
        imageView.setImageBitmap( photo );

  }

    super.onActivityResult( requestCodeC, resultCode, data );
}
```

on back pressed while in camera activity the app crashes, I think this is because data is remaining null.
How can I fix this?
Thanks,

Comment: We need more information to help you. You should provide a better description, the exception stacktrace, screenshots, logs.. anything that can help us to help you.

Comment: @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCodeC, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult( requestCodeC, resultCode, data );    
    // if this is the result of our camera image request
      
    
        if (requestCodeC == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            // getting bitmap of the image
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) Objects.requireNonNull( Objects.requireNonNull( data ).getExtras() ).get( "data" );
            // displaying this bitmap in imageview
            imageView.setImageBitmap( photo );
    
      }
    
       
    }

Comment: add this code and run.

Answer (score 0):

First, start by checking `resultCode`. You are ignoring it. You should see whether or not it is `RESULT_OK`; if it is not, then do not attempt to read the extra.

Second, be more graceful about handling strange results. There are ~3 billion Android users, using tens of thousands of device models and hundreds of camera apps. Some camera apps will have bugs. Crashing *your* app, because the *camera app* has a bug, is not a great user experience.